# AjaxToolkit e HtmlEditorFieldExtender. Demonstração do conteúdo

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ajaxtoolkit

Estou utilizando o `HtmlEditorExtender` do ***AjaxToolkit*** e nele habilitei a opção de poder inserir uma imagem ao corpo do texto.

```cs
<asp:TextBox ID="txtDescricao" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Rows="5" 
    Width="100%" Height="100%"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator SetFocusOnError="True" runat="server"  
ControlToValidate="txtDescricao" ValidationGroup="SalvarNoticia">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<ajaxtoolkit:HtmlEditorExtender runat="server" ID="heeDescricao"
    TargetControlID="txtDescricao" DisplaySourceTab="true" EnableSanitization="false" 
    OnImageUploadComplete="heeDescricao_ImageUploadComplete">
    <Toolbar>
        ...
        <ajaxtoolkit:InsertImage />
        ...
    </Toolbar>
</ajaxtoolkit:HtmlEditorExtender>
```

Em uma outra página separei uma `<div>` para demonstrar o conteúdo do texto.
Então fiz assim:

```cs
<asp:Panel ID="pnlDescricao" SkinID="PanelMain" runat="server" Height="70px">
    <div id="txtDescricao" runat="server">
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

E no *Code-Behind* dessa pagina de demonstração retorno o texto dessa forma:

```cs
var obj = new Business.Texto().Obter(id);
if (obj != null)
{
    ...
    txtDescricao.InnerHtml = obj.Descricao;
    ...
}
```

Estou utilizando o SQL Server e salvo o conteúdo em um campo do tipo ***text***, e carrego para uma propriedade do tipo `string`.

A tela renderiza o código html, e não a imagem em si:

Exemplo:

[image: Exemplo de renderização]

E o fonte do html ao inspecionar o elemtno aparece assim:

```html
<div id="CPHConsultaBody_pnlDescricao" 
    class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" 
    style="height:70px;padding:2px;margin-top:2px;padding:5px;">
    <div id="CPHConsultaBody_txtDescricao">
        &lt;imgsrc="/Arquivos/temp/20140603091536649/wall-smiley.jpg"&gt;</div>        
</div>
```

**Como posso resolver esse problema**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use no lugar dessa div um [Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), e coloque o [`mode="Transform"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.literal.mode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), para que ele processo um [Html](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) ou [XHtml](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xhtml).

*Exemplo:*

***ASPX:***

```cs
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="txtDescricao" runat="server"></div> 
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ID="LiteralDescricao" ClientIDMode="Static" Mode="Transform"></asp:Literal>   
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

***Código:***

```cs
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtDescricao.InnerText = "<img src='Content/1.png' border='0' width='50%' />";
        LiteralDescricao.Text = "<img src='Content/1.png' border='0' width='50%' />";
    }
}
```

***Resultado:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```cs
<div>
     <div id="txtDescricao">&lt;img src=&#39;Content/1.png&#39; border=&#39;0&#39; width=&#39;25%&#39; /&gt;</div> 
     <img src='Content/1.png' border='0' width='25%' />   
</div>
```

Perceba que na div ele fez o `Encode` e no [Literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.Literal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ele processou `Html` com aquela configuração de `mode="Transform"`. Só lembrando que o Literal também faz o Encode quando o `mode="Encode"`.

***Obs:*** se vier do seu banco com os caracteres (Encode) utilize antes da atribuição um [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

*Exemplo:*

```cs
LiteralDescricao.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(obj.Descricao);
```

Comment: @TremDoido você colocou assim: `<asp:Literal runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ID="LiteralDescricao" ClientIDMode="Static" Mode="Transform"></asp:Literal>` ? com Mode="Transform" ?

Comment: @TremDoido faça um Debug na atribuição `obj.Descricao;` antes de jogar no Literal e fale para mim como ta vindo a String do Banco?

Comment: Vou editar e você coloque no seu código